# QGIS 3.6.0 when shutting down hangs with 'Running checks' message

Tags: qgis-3, windows-10

When I have used the Layout Manager to print several different layouts, then go to exit from QGIS (Windows 10), I get a message that the shutdown cannot complete because QGIS is 'Running Checks' and the program just hangs. Eventually, I kill it.